# Calling header of library with dependency linux machine

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Please help to rephrase the question.

I am going to use *systemc* library in my code.
There are `Dir1/systemc.a` and `Dir2/systemc.h` files in the library directory. There are also some other files like: `Makefile.in` `Makefile.am` and `CMakeLists.txt`

I have a simple *helloworld* application:

```
#include <systemc.h>

SC_MODULE(and2){
    ...
```

Here is how I try to run it

```
gcc -I/Dir2 helloworld.c /Dir1/systemc.a -o helloworld
```

Here is the error that I get:

> fatal error: cassert: No such file or directory
>
> #include <cassert>^

It is part of systemc.h code. So it seems I am missing some dependencies here.
The other issue is that I don't have sudo privilege on this machine, and cmake is also not installed.

Comment: cassert is a C++ header, but you are compiling helloworld.c which is just C (deduced by compiler through the file suffix). Try compiling for C++ instead.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks. that was right, it needs to be cpp

Answer (score 0):

As @Andreas mentioned, I was compiling helloworld.c :(

Had to change it to helloworld.cpp :)